# How to open mod if 3 mods give same critical point?

Tags: inequality

For example in the question $$|x|^2-|x|+3<=3|x|-1$$

we have 3 modulus giving the same critical point ie 0.
How am I supposed to open the mod?

If I consider only +++ and --- I get the answer $x$ belong to Pfi
But the answer is $[-2,2]$

Comment: How can the answer be $[-2,2]$ for instance check for $x=0$

Comment: What is Pfi? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Did you mean to use $\le$ instead of $<$, and the answer $\{-2,2\}$ instead of $[-2,2]$?

Comment: You do realise that $a^2$ and $|a|^2$ are the same? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let $|x|=t$ So we have $$t^2-t+3<3t-1$$ $$\implies t^2-4t+4<0$$
$$\implies (t-2)^2<0$$ But this can't be true for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ Hence we conclude no such $t$ exists.

Now, $t=|x|$ If no $t$ exists, it means that no $|x|$ exists or consequently no such $x$ exists.

Comment: Yeah I got the same but that's not the correct answer

Comment: I fear that the answer you have is wrong then....unless i do not interpret the question correctly

Comment: Yeah the sign is less than equal to not just equal to. I got the ans. Thanks mate!

Comment: @MahekPatel welcome...and can you pls tell what does pfi mean

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad I think they meant $\phi$ (phi), which is used to denote an empty set.

Comment: @Utkarsh ahh i see...that makes sense